# unknown size from stacked tensorArray in tf.while_loop output

Tags: tensorflow

The following code uses a `tf.while_loop(...)` for computations of a dynamic length.

```
    outputs_tensor_array = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32,
                                          size=0,
                                          clear_after_read=False,
                                          infer_shape=False,
                                          dynamic_size = True,
                                          element_shape[self.batch_size, self.size])

    initial_args = [outputs_tensor_array, 0]
    outputs, *_ = tf.while_loop(lambda out, idx, *_ : idx < max_len,
                                func,
                                initial_args + additional_args,
                                parallel_iterations = 32,
                                swap_memory = True)
    outputs = outputs.stack()
```

I'm wondering if its possible to enforce a size, or atleast make that size be `None` in order to enforce a size constraint and enable further computations down the graph. The current shape is `[?, batch, hidden_size]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tensor.set_shape` will refine the static shape information and throw an error if it is incompatible with current static shape information (in the TensorArray.stack() case it will let you set any value for the zeroth dimension's static shape information).

`tf.reshape` can also be useful for asserting/filling in shape information, although it's not perfect. It will only throw an error if the size of the Tensor is wrong when the graph is executed (and may otherwise hide a shape error downstream).

More complicated, but you can also `set_shape` for the static shape information and then use [tf.Assert](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Assert) with `tf.shape` to check the Tensor's shape when the graph is executed.